# Folder emulated as USB storage

Tags: windows, microsoft-virtual-pc

Is there a software that can emulate a folder from a PC disk as a usb storage? I need that in order to "share" the folder from Host OS (win7) into guest system (winXP) via virtualPC 6.1 (it has some "integrated features" which are supposed to work exactly for that...but in my case they don't..., I did use also "subst" from host but drives/folders still not visible on guest). So I don't need cables or to connect to a different PC, just on the local machine to emulate as usb storage (virtualPC can "see" the usb stick...so I'm trying this "workaround").
 Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using regular Windows File Sharing?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an application to do this.  Create an empty folder on an NTFS drive, share the folder, then mount the USB drive in that folder.  Mounting the USB drive can be done from `Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Computer Management/Disk Management`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However can you clarify your answer a little bit?

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/03/28/assign-usb-drives-to-a-folder/)?

Comment: @Jet Yes, that is what I meant.